# Zabbix IPMI does not auth with Cisco C220 M3

Tags: cisco, zabbix, ipmi

`server: Cisco C220 M3
Zabbix 2.4
Ubuntu 14.04`

ipmitool works

```
user1@zabbix3:~# ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.1.45 -U admin -P Password1 -A MD5 sel
SEL Information
Version : 1.5 (v1.5, v2 compliant)
Entries : 158
Free Space : 45600 bytes
Percent Used : 5%
Last Add Time : 03/05/2015 08:15:22
Last Del Time : 11/22/2014 05:25:06
Overflow : false
Supported Cmds : 'Reserve'
```

However, I have tried MD5, None, Default, and all others and I get one of the following errors in Zabbix:

```
Cannot connect to IPMI host: Error [22] invalid arguement (with MD5)
Cannot connect to IPMI host: 33554449 Unknown error 33554449
```

Privilege level: User

username and password are provided and verified correct.

Comment: I have this vague memory of Zabbix's IPMI implementation not using `lanplus` but I could be wrong. Most of the IPMI stuff I have is very old scripts before Zabbix supported discreet values that polls the IPMI and then uses the zabbix sender to get the data into Zabbix.

Comment: I re-installed OpenIPMI with SSL support. Then re-installed Zabbix which consumed the new OpenIPMI \w SSL. As per https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=46632&page=2 (post 13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar report on the Zabbix bug tracker at [ZBX-8681](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-8681), which was closed as a duplicate of [ZBX-7190](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7190). You might wish to add additional information (hardware, tcpdump, Zabbix log) to the latter issue.